# Postgres 9.6 - complex query jsonb field that consists array of jsons

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

My table looks something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE myjsontable(data JSONB NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO myjsontable VALUES ('[{"score":20 ,"category": 10 }, {"score":100 ,"category": 100 },{"score":500 ,"category": 50 }]');

INSERT INTO myjsontable VALUES ('[{"score":1000 ,"category": 40 }, {"score":30 ,"category": 50 },{"score":6000 ,"category": 100 }]');

INSERT INTO myjsontable VALUES ('[{"score":10 ,"category": 1 }, {"score":123 ,"category": 40 },{"score":1000 ,"category": 50 }]');

CREATE INDEX ON myjsontable USING GIN(data);
```

I want to fetch only the records that have category X **and** score above Y on specific json within array of jsons

All I've managed to do is using contains like that:

```
SELECT * FROM myjsontable WHERE data @> '[{ "category": 10}]';
```

I wish I could do something like for easy query (like NoSQL..)

```
 SELECT * FROM myjsontable WHERE data @> '[{ "category": 10, "score": ">10" }]';
```

Is there any way to do simple, yet complex, where clauses like in the example given when my field is an array of jsons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the category & score are stored as json objects in a json array, first the array has to be unnested, and then using json accessor functions the values compared in the where clause. It is necessary to convert the json to text before converting to int:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM myjsontable t
CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data) x
WHERE (x.value->>'category')::INT = 10 
  AND (x.value->>'score')::INT > 10
```

It is also possible to write this query using the `EXISTS` clause. This formulation is a slightly more explicit in its intent:

```
SELECT * FROM myjsontable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data) x
              WHERE (value->>'category')::INT = 10 
                AND (value->>'score')::INT > 10)
```

Comment: oops thanks for the note, let me update my answer for future readers